# Get current device QT using array?

Tags: qt

With this I get the path of my user:

```
QString homePath = QDir::homePath();
```

But I need to take the three first letters; I was thinking of changing qstring to qvector and then take the three letters and then return a string. Can someone share with me an example?

Comment: "I need to take the three first letters" I doubt that very much. Please explain why you think you need to do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
QString firstThreeLetters = homePath.mid(0, 3);
```

Comment: You also can use `QString::left(int n)`. It returns a substring that contains the n leftmost characters of the string.